# Concurrent Futures Does Not Continue After Exception

Tags: python, multithreading

I'm using concurrent futures to scrape a list of H1s from Webpages and append them to a list called archive_h1_list. The issue is, as soon as concurrent futures hits an exception, it stops appending the list.

When I print the resultant list below,  it stops after the first exception.   `['Example Domain', 'Example Domain', 'Exception Error!']` it never continues to process the last https://www.example.com h1 in the list after hitting an exception.

```
import concurrent.futures
from urllib.request import urlopen

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

CONNECTIONS = 8

archive_url_list = ["https://www.example.com", "https://www.example.com", "sdfihaslkhasd", "https://www.example.com"]
archive_h1_list = []

def get_archive_h1(h1_url):
    html = urlopen(h1_url)
    bsh = BeautifulSoup(html.read(), 'lxml')
    return bsh.h1.text.strip()


def concurrent_calls():
    with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=CONNECTIONS) as executor:
        f1 = executor.map(get_archive_h1, archive_url_list)
        try:
            for future in f1:
                archive_h1_list.append(future)
        except Exception:
            archive_h1_list.append("Exception Error!")
            pass
```

The expected output should be:

```
['Example Domain', 'Example Domain', 'Exception Error!', 'Example Domain']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because your `for` loop is inside `try` and when you catch the exception the `try` block is suspended and the `except` block is being executed, thus your `for` loop gets interrupted.

One way to solve it would be to move your for loop outside the `try` block however according to the documentation of `Executor.map`:

> If a func call raises an exception, then that exception will be raised when its value is retrieved from the iterator.

Which makes the exception handling pretty nasty outside of your function.

So the first solution is to catch the exceptions inside `get_archive_h1`:

```py
def get_archive_h1(h1_url):
    try:
        html = urlopen(h1_url)
        bsh = BeautifulSoup(html.read(), 'lxml')
        return bsh.h1.text.strip()
    except Exception:
       return "Exception Error!"


def concurrent_calls():
    with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=CONNECTIONS) as executor:
        f1 = executor.map(get_archive_h1, archive_url_list)
        for future in f1:
            archive_h1_list.append(future)
```

The other solution is to use a different executor method where you have more control over your future resolution, i.e. `Executor.submit`:

```py
def concurrent_calls():
    with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=CONNECTIONS) as executor:
        futures = [executor.submit(get_archive_h1, url) for url in archive_url_list]
        for future in futures:
            try:
                archive_h1_list.append(future.result())
            except Exception:
                archive_h1_list.append("Exception Error!")
                pass
```

Comment: Thanks so much! That makes sense. I need to use map because I need to return the list in the original order. Thanks for taking the time to explain that to me . Really appreciate it.